# Codes of some comprehensive symbols

Tags: symbols

I am trying to find codes of the following symbols and I could not find them anywhere.

[image]

and

[image]

They are similar to $\succ$. However I could not obtain them.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For future reference, have you tried the [comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)? It is very long especially when new but contains a lot of symbols that might be helpful

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to a published reference where these symbols are defined and used?  If so, it's possible to submit a request for them to be added to Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define them as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\succmid}{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\succ}}\mathrel{\mkern10mu\raisebox{0.1ex}{\ensuremath\shortmid}}}
\newcommand{\dashsucc}{\mathrel{\mathrlap{-}}\mathrel{\mkern0mu\succ}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$A\succmid B\dashsucc C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\mapsfromchar` provided by `stmaryrd` and my favorite trick `\ooalign`.

The minus sign has to be smashed to preserve the same bounding box as `\succ`.

I also add code for the corresponding reverse symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for \mapsfromchar

\NewDocumentCommand{\precbar}{}{\mapstochar\prec}
\NewDocumentCommand{\succbar}{}{\succ\mapsfromchar}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\precdash}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\spdash@\prec}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\succdash}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\spdash@\succ}}
\newcommand{\spdash@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \ooalign{\smash{$\m@th#1-$}\cr$\m@th#1#2$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \prec B \precbar C \succbar D \precdash E \succdash F$

$\scriptstyle A \prec B \precbar C \succbar D \precdash E \succdash F$

% show the bounding boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}

\fbox{$\succ$}\fbox{$\succbar$}\fbox{$\succdash$}

\end{document}
```

[image]